# GWT RPC using classes from another project on client side

Tags: java, gwt, netbeans

My question is similar to my [previous](https://web.archive.org/web/20151128201455/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357818/gwt-rpc-using-classes-from-jar-on-client-side) one, but this time I included the other project to my main project (I would like to use another project classes on my client side).
This is my package hierarchy:

[image: Package hierarchy]

The `Common.gwt.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
<source path="dal.entities"></source>
</module>
```

The `Main.gwt.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="">
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
<inherits name="org.rj.shared.Shared"/>
<inherits name="Common" />
<entry-point class="org.rj.client.MainEntryPoint"/>    
</module>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You might not be allowed to post pictures, but you are allowed (and encouraged!) to post code - *why* did you post screenshots of your code instead of the actual code? O_o

Comment: ok, i edit it, sorry. But i can't draw my package hierarchy from letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a hold of jpa-annotations-source.jar, [see comment 14](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1830#c14) and add it to your webproject classpath (the one with GWT). This should allow the GWT compiler to "see" the sources for the imports from your entity classes which I assume is causing problems. Hope it works! ;)

Comment: In the Project Properties window ->Libaries -> Compile I added the jar, but it's still not working.


Validating newly compiled units
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/F:/Documents%20and%20Settings/l/Dokumentumok/NetBeansProjects/RJ/src/java/org/rj/client/MainEntryPoint.java'
         [ERROR] Line 52: No source code is available for type dal.entities.Users; did you forget to inherit a required module?


Thanks anyway, I keep on trying.

Comment: Oh, make sure the DAL_Hibernate jar file is build ***with*** the sources. See Project properties->Build->Packaging, Exclude from jar file. Remove "**/*.java," part.

Comment: Strange. I have a similar project and the only notable difference is that the "Commons.gwt.xml" file is one level deep than yours (correspondig to your "dal" folder. and of course in Main.gwt.xml would be `<inherits name="dal.Common" />`

Comment: And that is the solution! I don't know why, but as soon as I made a 
"dal" package and put the Common.gwt.xml into that folder (dal.entities is now inside dal) it worked! (Of course I rewrited the Main.gwt.xml and also the Commons.gwt.xml, which looks like this now: <source path="entities"></source>) Thank you very much! I really owe you one, I've never guessed it. Thanks again!